# cannot start ssh in raspbian

Tags: raspbian, ssh

I have tried reinstalling ssh, starting ssh from `raspi-config`. Nothing seems to be working. When I typed in `/etc/init.d/ssh` it just goes to another line. No output. The same goes for any cmd like `/etc/initd.ssh start`

I have also tried regenerating ssh keys. This seems to have started after I install seafile. I am using https on seafile set up. I don't think I have changed any settings regarding ssh.
What is wrong with my ssh and What else could I try to start ssh?

[image]

Comment: have you tried sudo ssh restart? you can also do sudo service ssh status to check if it is running.

Comment: I have. It just take the command, and did nothing like in the screenshot. Anything along the lines of "sudo /etc/init.d/ssh *whatever*" results in just a new line with no output whatsoever.

Comment: If it's a fresh raspbian, and you didn't change anything, SSH should be enabled by default. To check if service is working, like Steve said, run `sudo service ssh status`

Comment: @Roijjer, try and drop the path, maybe it's not the application that you are looking to start (use only 'sudo ssh')? Are you trying to start ssh client or server?

Comment: Try `tail /var/log/syslog` after you run `sudo service ssh start` to see if there is any message there.

Comment: I tried "sudo service ssh status". It didn't return any output. Just went to a new line. I will post the output from tail /var/log/syslog soon..

Comment: Please see screenshot of output from tail /var/log/syslog here.
http://postimg.org/image/ev73k98yf/

Comment: First thing I would do is make sure openssh-server is actually installed. Assuming it is then I would edit /etc/init.d/ssh and add -v to the shebang line. Hopefully that will let you determine at what point in the script it is failing and hence let you figure out why it failed.